# Can blender composite in RGB space (or per-pixel)?

Tags: python, rendering, compositing-nodes, color

I'm trying to perform some colour operations on 2 render layers in order to find the regions where the images are the same. The operations are difference, i.e. absolute (dual) subtraction, which should produce black pixels where the images are both the same, and then inversion so that these regions become white whereas the differences are now dark.

The images I'm working with from my render layers are:

[image: 1] [image: 2]

These images are aligned so that the signs in each image are in the same place, so I would hope the difference images is near black for these areas.

I tried calculating the difference using the compositor node and got this result:

[image: difference_nodes]

It looks ok but from analysing the pixel values in each image I suspected it wasn't performing a per-pixel subtraction on each image to get the result (r-r,g-g,b-b). So I loaded them into gimp and did the difference operator there and got this result:

[image: difference_gimp]

This clearly looks completely different, so for a sanity check I manually did the difference operation in python:

```
def difference(imgA, imgB):
A = imgA.pixels[:]; B = imgB.pixels[:]
out = []

from numpy import subtract, absolute
out[0:len(A)] = absolute(subtract(A[0:len(A)], B[0:len(A)]))
out[3:len(A):4] = [ 1 for i in range(0, int(len(A)/4)) ]
    
output = D.images.new("Difference", imgA.size[0], imgA.size[1])
output.pixels = out[:]
```

and got the following result:

[image: difference_manual]

Now this looks closer to the gimp output but is still slightly different (perhaps due to the colour space gimp works in).

Similarly for the inversion blender compositor nodes produced this:

[image: inversion_nodes]

from the manual difference output, which looks completely rubbish and useless whereas doing the inversion manually or in gimp gave a much more logical result:

[image: inversion_manual]

My issue is that doing these operations manually in my blender script takes about 6 seconds each (and that's without having to save each render layer and reopen them as images since there's apparently no way to access raw render layers in python, giving > 15 seconds in total (and also leaving unnecessary render layers all over my hdd)).

On the other hand, blender can do these composite operations straight from the render layers in about 3.5seconds which is a massive difference considering this will run on many frames.

Is there anyway to change the operating domain of the blender nodes so that they produce the same results as the per-pixel operations in python?

Comment: Have you tried separating each channel and using math nodes to do the operations, then combine the channels back ?

Comment: I can't say it's responsible for all your problems, but Blender's compositor works, by default, in sRGB space, and runs an implicit color transform on the output.  Look at Display Device, View Transform and Sequencer fields in properties/render/color management.  You should probably set the sequencer to non-color and the display device to "none" (which disables the View Transform and works without any kind of color transform, gamma or other.)

Comment: it was indeed the display device settings, thanks